# Retrieving Texture Map coordinates from Object face Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to take a 3D Object in Three.js, look at a point on the surface of that object and find the corresponding point on a texture file (preferably with x,y coordinates).

Right now I'm casting a ray to find the point on the face of the object. Each point has a corresponding face that I think *should* somehow correspond to the texture map. Is there a known way of retrieving this information? (perhaps by somehow inverting the UV Mapping function?) If not I will continue to work on the problem and post a solution if I can figure it out.

Comment: Well, if you got the face (triangle), you got the 3 vertices that describe said face. And those have each a u - and v mapping corrdinate. Then you could be satisfied with the result or calculate the center of the three 2D-points that the UV-coordinates describe?

Comment: Use `THREE.Triangle.barycoordFromPoint( point, v1, v2, v3, barry )` to get the three barycentric coordinates of the intersection point within the triangle, and then apply the three weights in `barry` to the three UVs of the vertices of the triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in the following way:

```
//Find the Index of the face at the center of the screen

var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.5);
projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(object, true);

if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var index = intersects[0].faceIndex;
}

//Find the UV Coordinates of the the three vertices of the face at that index

var point1,point2,point3;
point1.x = objectGlobal.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][index][0].x;
point1.y = objectGlobal.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][index][0].y

point2.x = objectGlobal.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][index][1].x;
point2.y = objectGlobal.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][index][1].y;

point3.x = objectGlobal.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][index][2].x;
point3.y = objectGlobal.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][index][2].y;
```